# How can I downcast a pointer after passing it through a function?

Tags: c++, function, polymorphism, downcast

I created a function which returns a base pointer to a derived object which is created in the func.
It seems like it doesn't work! As if the derived data is lost, and the pointer is pointing to a base object...

There is class Request, which is the base class, 
and there is class loginRequest - which derives Request. In order to check the type of object, I printed the object's name (typeid(*r).name()).
Inside the func(), the printing output turned out to be "loginRequest", which is good because this is the pointed object. (look at the code)
BUT after returning this pointer, when I print it's type again, it turns out to be "Request". Can you guys please help me? why does the returned pointer lose the derived data?

```cpp
Request * r = new Request();
r = func(); // r is now supposed to point the LoginRequest object.
std::cout<< typeid(*r).name() <<std::endl; //print the type of OBJECT

//func
Request * func()
{
    Request * r;
    LoginRequest l = LoginRequest();
    r = &l;
    std::cout<< typeid(*r).name() <<std::endl;  //print the type of OBJECT
    return r; 
}
```

Comment: Your object is local; its gone as soon as the function returns.

Comment: the object "LoginRequest l " ? What should I do then?

Comment: Return by value or return a (smart) pointer to a dynamically allocated one.

Comment: Please don't use `new`. Use `std::unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're returning a pointer to an object, `l`, that has automatic storage duration.
Dereferencing the returned pointer has undefined behaviour.

You need to create that object dynamically with `new`, and remove the memory leak that's caused by your misuse of `new` outside the function:

```
Request* func()
{
    Request* r = new LoginRequest();
    std::cout<< typeid(*r).name() <<std::endl;  //print the type of OBJECT
    return r; 
}


// ...

Request * r = func();
std::cout << typeid(*r).name() << std::endl; //print the type of OBJECT
```

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a local `LoginRequest` object:

```
LoginRequest l = LoginRequest();
```

taking that address:

```
r = &l;
```

and returning it:

```
return r;
```

but `l` goes out of scope on the next line:

```
}
```

Instead you want to create it on the heap:

```
Request * func()
{
    Request * r;
    LoginRequest* l = new LoginRequest();
    r = l;
    std::cout<< typeid(*r).name() <<std::endl;  //print the type of OBJECT
    return r; 
}
```

Also use smart pointers rather than raw pointers.